# ASUS extended model number

Tags: asus-laptop

Many ASUS laptops have a suffix added to their model number. I'm wondering what this stands for and what the differences between machines with different suffixes can be?

For instance on my laptop, it says `BU401LA-FA273G`. According to the ASUS website, `BU401LA` is the model number. Then what does the `FA273G` mean? In general what can be the differences between my `BU401LA-FA273G` and, say, a `BU401LA-FA366G`?

(In particular I'd like to know whether the charging port can differ but please give a general answer so it may be of use to others.)